# Content lost in RecyclerView after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` to display a list of timeline, and each tweet of the timeline is shown as a `CardView`. But some contents of the cards are lost after the scrolling the `RecyclerView` down and scrolling back, as shown in the two screenshots below. The contents in the red rectangle is lost after scrolling.

**BEFORE SCROLLING:**

[image: initial screenshot]

**AFTER SCROLLING:**

[image: screenshot after scrolling]

I'm wondering whether or not it's a bug of `RecyclerView` and find no solution after Googling for it.

By the way, I wrote a class extending `Recycler.Adapter`, which contains two methods `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`. I put the ViewHolder's inflation work in the `onBindViewHolder` method. And I use a default `LinearLayoutManager` for the `RecyclerView`. I don't know if I should write a `LayoutManager` myself or not.

Comment: RecyclerView will reuse your cardview, if you scroll down. You should transfer the value of your edittext to your data model. Maybe the methods onViewRecycled/onViewDetachedFromWindow will help you.

Comment: @Christopher That's not a EditText though. It's a RelativeLayout containing multiple controls.

Comment: Ok, but this make no real difference on my statement. RecyclerView will reuse ("recycle") your views, if you scroll down/up.